# Router.use() requires middleware function but got a undefined at function use

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

im following this tutorial to work with authentication with node.js and i have some problems that i didn't figure out how to solve yet. Basicly i set the server **like this**

```
var express         = require('express');
var bodyParser      = require('body-parser'); // necessário para PUT e POST
var mongoose        = require('mongoose');
var expressLayouts  = require('express-ejs-layouts');
var passport        = require('passport');
var flash           = require('connect-flash');
var morgan          = require('morgan');
var cookieParser    = require('cookie-parser');
var session         = require('express-session');
var configDB        = require('./config/database.js');

// conexão à base de dados (o servidor MongoDB necessita já ter sido iniciado)
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise; //resolução de warning:
mongoose.connect(configDB.url);

//require('./config/passport')(passport); // pass passport for configuration

// Configura a aplicação Express (e seus middlewares)

var app = express();

app.use(morgan('dev')); // log every request to the console
app.use(cookieParser()); // read cookies (needed for auth)
app.use(bodyParser()); // get information from html forms

app.set('views', './views');
app.set('view engine','ejs');

app.use(session({ secret: 'ilovescotchscotchyscotchscotch' })); // session secret
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session()); // persistent login sessions
app.use(flash());

app.use(expressLayouts);
app.use(express.static('./public'));
app.use('/', require('./routes/register')(passport));
app.use('/', require('./routes/login')(passport));
app.use('/', require('./routes/profile')(passport));
app.use('/', require('./routes/main')(passport));
app.use('/', require('./routes/logout')(passport));

//middlewares de terceiros
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
//middlewares de roteamento

// inicia servidor
var server = app.listen(8081, function() {
 console.log('Express server listening on port ' + server.address().port);
});
```

i think the problem has something to do with my routes or the passport module to do the authentication.

**Here is my register route**

```
var User = require('../models/user');
var express = require('express');
// routeamento do Express
var router = express.Router();
//GET request - /movies
module.exports = function(passport) {

    router.route('/register')
        .get(function(req, res) {
            res.render('./pages/register',{ message: req.flash('signupMessage') });
        })
        .post(passport.authenticate('local-signup', {
            successRedirect : '/profile', // redirect to the secure profile section
            failureRedirect : '/register', // redirect back to the signup page if there is an error
            failureFlash : true // allow flash messages
        }));
}
```

to end this i need to show how my passport is set, i don't know very well what i am missing here and why i get that error, maybe it has something to do with the order of the middlewares?

**passport**

```
/ config/passport.js

// load all the things we need
var LocalStrategy   = require('passport-local').Strategy;
// load up the user model
var User            = require('../models/user');

// expose this function to our app using module.exports
module.exports = function(passport) {
    // =========================================================================
    // passport session setup ==================================================
    // =========================================================================
    // required for persistent login sessions
    // passport needs ability to serialize and unserialize users out of session

    // used to serialize the user for the session
    passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
        done(null, user.id);
    });

    // used to deserialize the user
    passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
        User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
            done(err, user);
        });
    });

    // =========================================================================
    // LOCAL SIGNUP ============================================================
    // =========================================================================
    // we are using named strategies since we have one for login and one for signup
    // by default, if there was no name, it would just be called 'local'

    passport.use('local-signup', new LocalStrategy({
        // by default, local strategy uses username and password, we will override with email
        usernameField : 'email',
        passwordField : 'password',
        passReqToCallback : true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback
    },
    function(req, email, password, done) {

        // asynchronous
        // User.findOne wont fire unless data is sent back
        process.nextTick(function() {

        // find a user whose email is the same as the forms email
        // we are checking to see if the user trying to login already exists
        User.findOne({ 'local.email' :  email }, function(err, user) {
            // if there are any errors, return the error
            if (err)
                return done(err);

            // check to see if theres already a user with that email
            if (user) {
                return done(null, false, req.flash('signupMessage', 'That email is already taken.'));
            } else {

                // if there is no user with that email
                // create the user
                var newUser            = new User();

                // set the user's local credentials
                newUser.local.email    = email;
                newUser.local.password = newUser.generateHash(password);

                // save the user
                newUser.save(function(err) {
                    if (err)
                        throw err;
                    return done(null, newUser);
                });
            }

        });    

        });

    }));

};
```

error on the cmd:

```
us);
        } else {
          var challenges = failures\.map(function(f) { return f\.challenge; });
          var statuses = failures\.map(function(f) { return f\.status; });
          return callback(null, false, challenges, statuses);
        }
      }

      \/\/ Strategies are ordered by priority\.  For the purpose of flashing a
      \/\/ message, the first failure will be displayed\.
      var failure = failures[0] || {}
        , challenge = failure\.challenge || {}
        , msg;

      if (options\.failureFlash) {
        var flash = options\.failureFlash;
        if (typeof flash == 'string') {
          flash = { type: 'error', message: flash };
        }
        flash\.type = flash\.type || 'error';

        var type = flash\.type || challenge\.type || 'error';
        msg = flash\.message || challenge\.message || challenge;
        if (typeof msg == 'string') {
          req\.flash(type, msg);
        }
      }
      if (options\.failureMessage) {
        msg = options\.failureMessage;
        if (typeof msg == 'boolean') {
          msg = challenge\.message || challenge;
        }
        if (typeof msg == 'string') {
          req\.session\.messages = req\.session\.messages || [];
          req\.session\.messages\.push(msg);
        }
      }
      if (options\.failureRedirect) {
        return res\.redirect(options\.failureRedirect);
      }

      \/\/ When failure handling is not delegated to the application, the defaul
t
      \/\/ is to respond with 401 Unauthorized\.  Note that the WWW-Authenticate

      \/\/ header will be set according to the strategies in use (see
      \/\/ actions#fail)\.  If multiple strategies failed, each of their challen
ges
      \/\/ will be included in the response\.
      var rchallenge = []
        , rstatus, status;

      for (var j = 0, len = failures\.length; j < len; j++) {
        failure = failures[j];
        challenge = failure\.challenge;
        status = failure\.status;

        rstatus = rstatus || status;
        if (typeof challenge == 'string') {
          rchallenge\.push(challenge);
        }
      }

      res\.statusCode = rstatus || 401;
      if (res\.statusCode == 401 && rchallenge\.length) {
        res\.setHeader('WWW-Authenticate', rchallenge);
      }
      if (options\.failWithError) {
        return next(new AuthenticationError(http\.STATUS_CODES[res\.statusCode],
 rstatus));
      }
      res\.end(http\.STATUS_CODES[res\.statusCode]);
    }

    (function attempt(i) {
      var layer = name[i];
      \/\/ If no more strategies exist in the chain, authentication has failed\.

      if (!layer) { return allFailed(); }

      \/\/ Get the strategy, which will be used as prototype from which to creat
e
      \/\/ a new instance\.  Action functions will then be bound to the strategy

      \/\/ within the context of the HTTP request\/response pair\.
      var prototype = passport\._strategy(layer);
      if (!prototype) { return next(new Error('Unknown authentication strategy "
' + layer + '"')); }

      var strategy = Object\.create(prototype);


      \/\/ ----- BEGIN STRATEGY AUGMENTATION -----
      \/\/ Augment the new strategy instance with action functions\.  These acti
on
      \/\/ functions are bound via closure the the request\/response pair\.  The
 end
      \/\/ goal of the strategy is to invoke (.*)one(.*) of these action methods
, in
      \/\/ order to indicate successful or failed authentication, redirect to a
      \/\/ third-party identity provider, etc\.

      \/(.*)(.*)
       (.*) Authenticate `user`, with optional `info`\.
       (.*)
       (.*) Strategies should call this function to successfully authenticate a
       (.*) user\.  `user` should be an object supplied by the application after
 it
       (.*) has been given an opportunity to verify credentials\.  `info` is an
       (.*) optional argument containing additional user information\.  This is
       (.*) useful for third-party authentication strategies to pass profile
       (.*) details\.
       (.*)
       (.*) @param {Object} user
       (.*) @param {Object} info
       (.*) @api public
       (.*)\/
      strategy\.success = function(user, info) {
        if (callback) {
          return callback(null, user, info);
        }

        info = info || {};
        var msg;

        if (options\.successFlash) {
          var flash = options\.successFlash;
          if (typeof flash == 'string') {
            flash = { type: 'success', message: flash };
          }
          flash\.type = flash\.type || 'success';

          var type = flash\.type || info\.type || 'success';
          msg = flash\.message || info\.message || info;
          if (typeof msg == 'string') {
            req\.flash(type, msg);
          }
        }
        if (options\.successMessage) {
          msg = options\.successMessage;
          if (typeof msg == 'boolean') {
            msg = info\.message || info;
          }
          if (typeof msg == 'string') {
            req\.session\.messages = req\.session\.messages || [];
            req\.session\.messages\.push(msg);
          }
        }
        if (options\.assignProperty) {
          req[options\.assignProperty] = user;
          return next();
        }

        req\.logIn(user, options, function(err) {
          if (err) { return next(err); }

          function complete() {
            if (options\.successReturnToOrRedirect) {
              var url = options\.successReturnToOrRedirect;
              if (req\.session && req\.session\.returnTo) {
                url = req\.session\.returnTo;
                delete req\.session\.returnTo;
              }
              return res\.redirect(url);
            }
            if (options\.successRedirect) {
              return res\.redirect(options\.successRedirect);
            }
            next();
          }

          if (options\.authInfo !== false) {
            passport\.transformAuthInfo(info, req, function(err, tinfo) {
              if (err) { return next(err); }
              req\.authInfo = tinfo;
              complete();
            });
          } else {
            complete();
          }
        });
      };

      \/(.*)(.*)
       (.*) Fail authentication, with optional `challenge` and `status`, default
ing
       (.*) to 401\.
       (.*)
       (.*) Strategies should call this function to fail an authentication attem
pt\.
       (.*)
       (.*) @param {String} challenge
       (.*) @param {Number} status
       (.*) @api public
       (.*)\/
      strategy\.fail = function(challenge, status) {
        if (typeof challenge == 'number') {
          status = challenge;
          challenge = undefined;
        }

        \/\/ push this failure into the accumulator and attempt authentication
        \/\/ using the next strategy
        failures\.push({ challenge: challenge, status: status });
        attempt(i + 1);
      };

      \/(.*)(.*)
       (.*) Redirect to `url` with optional `status`, defaulting to 302\.
       (.*)
       (.*) Strategies should call this function to redirect the user (via their

       (.*) user agent) to a third-party website for authentication\.
       (.*)
       (.*) @param {String} url
       (.*) @param {Number} status
       (.*) @api public
       (.*)\/
      strategy\.redirect = function(url, status) {
        \/\/ NOTE: Do not use `res\.redirect` from Express, because it can't dec
ide
        \/\/       what it wants\.
        \/\/
        \/\/       Express 2\.x: res\.redirect(url, status)
        \/\/       Express 3\.x: res\.redirect(status, url) -OR- res\.redirect(u
rl, status)
        \/\/         - as of 3\.14\.0, deprecated warnings are issued if res\.re
direct(url, status)
        \/\/           is used
        \/\/       Express 4\.x: res\.redirect(status, url)
        \/\/         - all versions (as of 4\.8\.7) continue to accept res\.redi
rect(url, status)
        \/\/           but issue deprecated versions

        res\.statusCode = status || 302;
        res\.setHeader('Location', url);
        res\.setHeader('Content-Length', '0');
        res\.end();
      };

      \/(.*)(.*)
       (.*) Pass without making a success or fail decision\.
       (.*)
       (.*) Under most circumstances, Strategies should not need to call this
       (.*) function\.  It exists primarily to allow previous authentication sta
te
       (.*) to be restored, for example from an HTTP session\.
       (.*)
       (.*) @api public
       (.*)\/
      strategy\.pass = function() {
        next();
      };

      \/(.*)(.*)
       (.*) Internal error while performing authentication\.
       (.*)
       (.*) Strategies should call this function when an internal error occurs
       (.*) during the process of performing authentication; for example, if the

       (.*) user directory is not available\.
       (.*)
       (.*) @param {Error} err
       (.*) @api public
       (.*)\/
      strategy\.error = function(err) {
        if (callback) {
          return callback(err);
        }

        next(err);
      };

      \/\/ ----- END STRATEGY AUGMENTATION -----

      strategy\.authenticate(req, options);
    })(0); \/\/ attempt
  }\/?$/: Nothing to repeat
    at RegExp (native)
    at pathtoRegexp (C:\Users\Filipe\ShareIdea\node_modules\path-to-regexp\index
.js:128:10)
    at new Layer (C:\Users\Filipe\ShareIdea\node_modules\express\lib\router\laye
r.js:45:17)
    at Function.route (C:\Users\Filipe\ShareIdea\node_modules\express\lib\router
\index.js:494:15)
    at EventEmitter.app.(anonymous function) [as post] (C:\Users\Filipe\ShareIde
a\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:480:30)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\Filipe\ShareIdea\routes\routes.js:14:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Filipe\ShareIdea\app.js:43:30)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:509:3
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the order of middlewares matter. You should place these:
`app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));` on the top of your routes or any other middleware that are suppose to receive data, otherwise any data that you may get in your server, will not be parsed by the `body-parser`, and `req.body` will always be undefined.

Comment: solved that but now i get a strange error related to the passport and connect flash module, you have any idea how to catch the possible errors behind that, i edit the question